# Use environment variable in SFTP path in Paramiko

Tags: python, shell, sftp, paramiko

I'm running a script on my server and trying to get some files from my Firewall. I get a "file not found" error when referring to the file using an environment variable (`$` sign). B, but I can get my file when I enter a normal path. I'm aware that the code doesn't look good, this is just an quick example. Here is my working code:

```python
_savedLocation = "/home/kartal/Desktop/aaa.tgz"
folder, savedLocation = os.path.split(_savedLocation)
remotepath = "$FWDIR/bin/upgrade_tools/"
remotefile = remotepath + savedLocation
stdin, stdout, stderr =
  ssh.exec_command("cd {} && yes | ./migrate export {} ".format(remotepath, savedLocation))
time.sleep(120)
command = "cd {} && chmod 777 {}".format(remotepath, savedLocation)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotefile, _savedLocation)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

If I use real path as `remotepath = "/opt/r80/fw1/bin/upgrade_tools/"`, the code works.

Btw, I'm running the "migrate" script in the first step with `$FWDIR`. So `$FWDIR` works with `exec_command`, but not in SFTP `get`.

Where am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Can you download that file using any (even GUI) SFTP client?

Comment: Yes i can download the file in first code or gui.

Comment: What do you mean by "in first code"?

Comment: as I wrote in my question I'm talking about my working code.

Comment: But I'm asking if you can download file from "$FWDIR/bin/upgrade_tools/".

Comment: What is `$FWDIR`? Is that environment variable on the server?

Comment: $FWDIR is my firewall's specific directory.

Comment: OK, so can you answer, if you can download a file from `$FWDIR/bin/upgrade_tools/` using GUI SFTP client?

Comment: If you're talking about winscp, I can get the file, yes.

Comment: Post a WinSCP log file for the download.

Comment: https://ufile.io/meisf here is winscp log file. Btw I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use environment variables in SFTP. You have to use real paths. In this case the real path is `/opt/CPsuite-R80/fw1`.

If the real path is not fixed, and you really need to obtain the real path from a variable value, you will need to resolve the variable value using a different interface (e.g. using a shell access). And then use the resolved value in SFTP. This is what you do in WinSCP - you execute `cd $FWDIR` in the shell. And the shell resolves `$FWDIR` to `/opt/CPsuite-R80/fw1`. In Paramiko, you can use `SSHClient.exec_command` to resolve the variable:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo $FWDIR")
fwdir = stdin.read()
```

Comment: Thank you Martin I appreciate you taking the time!